# Styling markdown syntax not rendering markdown in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, markdown

I have no preference so far as to which markdown renderer to use (although I'm currently using [MMMarkdown](https://github.com/mdiep/MMMarkdown))

I would like to style the actual markdown (leaving markdown syntax in place) rather than render the markdown to a separate pane/window.

How should I go about achieving this?

For example:
`# Heading` -> should display as a heading but with the `#` still there, not as `<h1>Heading</h1>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEG Markdown Highlight](http://hasseg.org/peg-markdown-highlight/) does everything that I needed. It also provides a nice style template format for switching between markdown syntax styles.